# PHP - How to protect the URL after logging in from copy paste

Tags: php, authentication

I have created a login script and the user, after entering his username and password, is redirected to the main page of the site named `main.php`, if of course entering valid data.

I have seen that by copying and paste the URL of this page to another explorer, the page opens succesfully without the need to do the logging process.
How can I stop this? Hcan I protect my `main.php` page so that only users after a registration process can only see it?

Comment: there are a lot of good login tutorials on the web ... you need to keep in mind that an authenticated user can open up any number of tabs he wishes to , if he uses another browser, it won't work ... the script should restrict him ... you didn't tell us if main.php contains a routine to check if the user is authenticated or if his session expired

Comment: Show us the login code used on login page and the code that checks whether the user is logged in or not used on main page.

Answer (score 3):

Use session cookies instead of putting the session ID in the URL.

Comment: May be there is no session checking?

Answer (score 1):

Use session variables.

Here are some resources:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php